# Is there a way of iterating over Entity tables

Tags: .net, linq

I'm working with an old legacy project where interactions with the database are done via `System.Data.Linq`'s `DataContext`. I need to run tasks on some tables every day, but I need to loop over all tables starting with a particular letter (in this case it is 'x') and delete entries that are past a certain threshold.

So, is there a way to do that (iterate over tables starting with 'x'), or do I need to write the logic for each table individually?

Comment: Which ORM do you use? And what you are trying to do with tables?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - LINQ to SQL and in each table I need to delete entries that are older than one year. All the tables have a property `DT` that indicates the time of insertion, I will be deleting based on that.

Comment: Check [this one](https://debugmode.net/2010/12/28/get-all-the-tables-name-using-linq/), and better to generated `DELETE` SQL, it will be more performant.